# Swift Parse - local datastore and displaying objects in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-datastore

I am building and app that saves an object in the local datastore with parse. I then run a query to retrieve the objects that are in the local datastore and it is working fine. however, I would like to grab the object, and the contents in it, and set some labels in a table view cell based on the items that are stored in the parse local data store object. for example, i make an object with attributes like "objectID", "name", "date", "location". what i'd like to do is to have a table view on the home screen that displays the name, date, location ...etc. of each item that was saved in local datastore in labels in each cell.

i know that im saving it correctly:

```
// parse location object

    let parseLighthouse = PFObject(className: "ParseLighthouse")
    parseLighthouse.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "User")
            parseLighthouse["Name"] = self.placeTitle.text
            parseLighthouse["Note"] = self.placeNote.text
            parseLighthouse["Locality"] = self.placeDisplay.text!
            parseLighthouse["Latt"] = self.map.region.center.latitude
            parseLighthouse["Longi"] = self.map.region.center.longitude
            parseLighthouse["LattDelta"] = 0.5
            parseLighthouse["LongiDelta"] = 0.5
            parseLighthouse["Date"] = dateInFormat
            parseLighthouse.pinInBackground()
            parseLighthouse.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                println("Object has been saved. ID = \(parseLighthouse.objectId)")
            }
```

and when i run the query, im able to access the attributes by running println(object.objectForKey("Name"))

```
func performQuery() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "ParseLighthouse")

    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) lighthouses.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let light = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in light {
                    println(object.objectId)
                    println(object.objectForKey("Name"))



                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

because when running the query, i get back the object id and name as expected.

Successfully retrieved 2 lighthouses.
Optional("A3OROVAMIj")
Optional(happy)
Optional("bbyqPZDg8W")
Optional(date test)

what I would like to do is grab the name field within the parse object local data store, and that be the name of the label on a cell in a table view controller.

i dont know how to access that info from the object, and set the label correctly.

does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: Do you have your tableView ready? So you can start accessing the data from parse and displaying it there? or you are asking how to do the tableView with parse.com data?

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting an object back that is called "object" but it is in fact a custom class object that you are working with?  Have you tried casting it to the actual class and accessing the property that way?  In Objective C you would do something like this to access the name property: ((PFUser*)object).name although I'm not sure what the swift equivalent is.

Comment: so you query function is working right, you should want to get those information then load all cells in your tableview... Right??

Comment: yeah i currently have a table view setup. I guess my main issue is having trouble accessing the properties in the parse object.when I make one it saves with the customer class "ParseLighthouse" and in that object there is a name, latitude longitude note date...etc. I want to be able to grab those names notes...etc from ParseLighthouse and set that as labels in my travel view

Comment: just give me a second, i am writing the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea  to avoid pointer lol ... so why not saving the userid or username with the specific object..
so change this line:

```
 parseLighthouse.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "User")
```

TO

```
 parseLighthouse["username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username
```

**Answer**

NOW let's create a struct that contains **the objectID  and the Name** outside of your Controller Class.

```
struct Data
{
var Name:String!
var id:String!
}
```

then inside of the Controller class, declare the following  line of code globally

```
 var ArrayToPopulateCells = [Data]()
```

Then your query function will look like :

```
 func performQuery() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "ParseLighthouse")

    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) lighthouses.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let light = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in light {
                    print(object.objectId)
                    print(object.objectForKey("Name"))
                    var singleData = Data()
                    singleData.id = object.objectId
                    singleData.Name = object["Name"] as! String

                    self.ArrayToPopulateCells.append(singleData)


                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

**In the tableView numberOfRowinSection()**

```
return ArrayToPopulateCells.count
```

**In the cellForRowAtIndexPath()**

```
       var data = ArrayToPopulateCells[indexPath.row]
       cell.textlabel.text = data.objectID
       cell.detailLabel.text = data.Name
```

**VOila that should be it**

Comment: ok i followed your instructions and they seemed to be doing alright, no errors. but nothing is showing up in the table view. i followed the code exactly and theres nothing there. im not entirely sure that the items are being added to the arrayToPopulateCells array. any ideas?

Comment: Did you reload the tableview

Comment: yes and it's working now. thanks. another question, do you know how I could now swipe to delete an item in the cell from local data store and from parse.com?

Comment: I think that method is called **commiteditingstyle()** once enables it choose the delete style then you could swipe to delete

Comment: any idea on how to target the parse object within the commitededitingstyle method? I'm able to swipe and delete the cell but want to target the parse object and unpin it and delete it. the parse docs help but I can't seem to get it right

Comment: you have to post your code or we could continue in chat

Comment: where can we continue in chat?

Comment: i posted this in its own question with code here  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464778/parse-swift-unpin-an-item-in-table-view-cell