# parse swift - unpin an item in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

i would like to unpin an item that is in my tableview cell from parse. I save the object on another page, and query it in the main page, add that object to an array so it can be displayed in the table view. Now im not sure how to correctly select the corresponding parse object with whats in the array so that i can unpin it.

ideally i'd like to do this using the objectId just in case a user saves an object with the same name. how can i grab the objectId of whats displaying in my cell, and unpin it?

what query i use to add my objects to the array to then be displayed in my table view

```
var selectedLighthouse: localData? = nil


var arrayToPopulateCells = [localData]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    //query
        let query = PFQuery(className: "ParseLighthouse")

        query.fromLocalDatastore()
        query.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) lighthouses.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let lighthouse = objects {

                    self.arrayToPopulateCells.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                    for object in lighthouse {

                        var singleData = localData()
                        singleData.name = object["Name"] as! String
                        singleData.note = object["Note"] as! String
                        singleData.date = object["Date"] as! String
                        singleData.latt = object["Latt"] as! NSNumber
                        singleData.longi = object["Longi"] as! NSNumber
                        singleData.lattDelta = object["LattDelta"] as! NSNumber
                        singleData.longiDelta = object["LongiDelta"] as! NSNumber
                        singleData.locality = object["Locality"] as! String


                        self.arrayToPopulateCells.append(singleData)

                    }

                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }

        }
    //setting table view datasource and delegate.
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    println(currentUser)


}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    // var lighthouse = self.lighthouses[indexPath.row]
    var data = self.arrayToPopulateCells[indexPath.row]

    //setting the prototype cell to link with the identifier set in attributes earlier.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("locationCell") as! lighthouseCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.cellName.text = data.name
    cell.cellPlace.text = data.locality
    // cell.cellCoordinates.text = "\(lighthouse.latt)" + ", " + "\(lighthouse.longi)"
    // cell.cellNote.text = lighthouse.note
    cell.cellDate.text = "\(data.date)"

    return cell
}






func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedLighthouse = self.arrayToPopulateCells[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("lighthouseDetailViewSegue", sender: self)
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        var arrayObjectId = localData()
        var queryLocal = PFQuery(className:"ParseLighthouse")
        queryLocal.fromLocalDatastore()
        queryLocal.whereKey("Name", equalTo: arrayObjectId.name)
        queryLocal.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(arrayObjectId.name) {
            (parseLighthouse: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && parseLighthouse != nil {
                parseLighthouse?.unpinInBackground()
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }
        self.arrayToPopulateCells.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **commitediting()** method you don't need to query again  because your array already has all the data from parse so you just need to delete straight from the array then reloadData().

You just need:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
{
  var object:PFObject = self.arrayToPopulateCells[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
 object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock() // so check the if error == nil 
 self.arrayToPopulateCells.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
 tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
 self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: when i just have that code, i swipe, and the cell gets deleted but when the table reloads itself, that cell i just tried to delete appears again because the parse object is still in local datastore. i want to delete the cell AND unpin the object so when the table reloads its gone for good.

Comment: Did you add the reloadData()

Comment: yes. but when the viewdidload method runs, thats where my query is to get the objects in local datastore, and add them to the array, therefore when that runs, because the parse object was never actually unpinned (just the cell was deleted) the object still gets appended into the array, and still shows up in the table. when the cell gets deleted, i need to unpin the parse object at the same time but dont know how to target that object thats associated with that cell from the array.

Comment: app wont build. on object.deleteInBackground() i get " ' localData ' does not have a member named 'deleteInBackground'

Comment: Take out that localdata line

Comment: which one?

var selectedLighthouse: localData? = nil


var arrayToPopulateCells = [localData]()

Comment: still wont build. same error. localData does not have member named deletinbackground

Comment: Use with the deletewithbackroundblock my friend

Comment: just copied and ran your latest code update, now i get the error:

cast from 'localData' to unrelated type 'PFObject' always fails

Comment: So take out the as! pfobject